# 1990s/2000s live-action show with kids in tribes in a dystopian sci-fi/fantasy setting

Tags: story-identification, tv

I've been trying to find/remember this show for years but unfortunately I don't remember much except that:

- It was live action.
- I think it was some sort of dystopian sci-fi/fantasy setting where there were kids in different tribes or clans.
- I'm not sure if it was Australian or not but I watched it on Australian TV.
- I think I remember a lot of it taking place in the forest or somewhere foresty.
- There was an evil tribe and I think they had technology or something sci-fi thematically.

This show is literally my white whale. I'm starting to think I imagined the whole thing.

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. Incorrect answers are an excellent opportunity to [edit] in things not mentioned that don't match the incorrect answer.

Answer (score 16):

Might it be *[The Tribe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tribe_(1999_TV_series))*, a 1999 New Zealand production?

[image: Title card for The Tribe]

> Primarily aimed at teenagers, The Tribe is set in a post-apocalyptic city in which all adults have been killed as the result of an unknown virus. The series focuses on the remaining children and teenagers who must navigate the social and personal issues of adolescence, while being faced with the larger problems of a society in a state of anarchy. The inhabitants of the city form social groups, or tribes, with the focus of the series on the Mall Rats, who fight to survive among other threatening tribes such as the Locos. Overarching themes include the focus on change from tradition, empowerment, religion, and the exploration of power and corruption. The series was filmed in Wellington, New Zealand.

Found with a search for `australian live action tv show kids tribes`

It sounds like later seasons are more centered around forests and beaches, and the [Technos tribe](https://thetribe.fandom.com/wiki/Technos) are antagonists with advanced technology.

[image: The Technos]

> The Technos are a highly intelligent and advanced group of people led by a wheelchair bound genius, Ram, who invaded the City in order to bring order to the chaos. They truly believe that they are benefiting all those who live in the City by restoring electricity, food and water, and all for just some co-operative labor on the citizens part.
>
> Though the Technos do not possess extremely large numbers, they more than make up for this disadvantage by the technology that they wield: which includes zappers and Reality Space capabilities. They managed to capture half of the city's population, most of whom were used as Reality Space guinea pigs or shipped off by plane and sold into slavery.

### Trailer

Comment: At least in subsequent seasons, the focus of the action is on a beach next to a forest.

Comment: Damn, that was freaky stuff right there...

Answer (score 8):

Might be [*The Odyssey*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Odyssey_(TV_series)), a Canadian series released 1992-94; I watched it in the UK and it looks like it was broadcast quite widely although can't specifically see Australia. I think I only saw it once but it was quite striking and left a lot of vague memories for years afterwards.

The premise is that Jay, the protagonist, is in a coma after a fall and dreams/hallucinates living in the 'Downworld'. This is populated entirely by children with real world friends and rivals reflected in the people of the Downworld. There are definite dystopian themes, with the Tower - the most powerful tribe led by the 15 year old Brad - shown as a police state owning much of the obvious technology.

There are various settings, but forest scenes are prominent.

Trailer:

Answer (score 3):

Wrong timeframe (2014), but the description fits [*The 100*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_100_(TV_series)).

- live action
- dystopian Sci-Fi setting
- mostly in the forest
- mostly young people you could call 'kids'
- various tribes